# Cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

The following code:

```
age.equals( otherPerson.age );
```

Produces a compile error like:

`Cannot be dereferenced.`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Start by editing your question to include more details.  For a start, we need to see the declarations for `age` and `otherPerson`.

Answer (score 5):

it's hard to tell from your minimalistic question, but i'll guess that `age` is a [primitive](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and therefore doesn't have any methods.

try using `age == otherPerson.age` instead.